# NodeJS and Grunt build

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am new to NodeJS and Grunt world. I am working on a project where we have multiple modules dependent on each other. So my question how can I automate my process of build for each of projects(modules)
like currently when I take update, I have to manually go in each of projects and have to run

```
npm install
```

and then

```
grunt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we'd need a little more information on what your project is and how its setup.  Overall though, if you have several projects, each that uses grunt to build it, you'll need to run grunt for each one.

The way I handle this is to use TMUX, and more specifically TMUXINATOR https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator to setup workspaces for each of my projects.  For example, I might type:

```
mux service-framework
```

Doing so could launch (for example), four terminals, my editor, start several grunt projects, and load a browser.  Its a great tool for the situation you described.

There are a lot of tools for doing this type of thing, TMUX and TMUXINATOR are only one.  Hopefully this helps a bit!